# Add target="_blank" using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am updating some jQuery code and i need to add "target="_blank"" to the links in the code below. Unfortunately I am not that into jQuery and have not written the original code myself.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

This is what the code looks like:

```
<script>

        var console = {log:function(){}}
        var _frames;
        var _activeLink=0;
        var _links = 
        [
            "http://www.transavia.com/hv/main/nav/processflightqry?toDay=23&toMonth=2014-07&lang=fr&adults=1&from=ORY&fromMonth=2014-07&to=MAD&country=FR&infants=0&children=0&fromDay=16&opensearchform=true&tab=cal",
            "http://www.transavia.com/hv/main/nav/processflightqry?toDay=23&toMonth=2014-04&lang=fr&adults=1&from=ORY&fromMonth=2014-04&to=PRG&country=FR&infants=0&children=0&fromDay=16&opensearchform=true&tab=cal",
            "http://www.transavia.com/hv/main/nav/processflightqry?toDay=23&toMonth=2014-04&lang=fr&adults=1&from=ORY&fromMonth=2014-04&to=SAW&country=FR&infants=0&children=0&fromDay=16&opensearchform=true&tab=cal",
            "http://www.transavia.com/hv/main/page?id=destinations&lang=fr&country=FR"
        ]
        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            $(window).load(function()
            {
                resetPrice();
                // start the banner //
                _frames = ["trip1","trip2","trip3","lastFrame"];
                for(var i = 0;i<_frames.length;i++)
                {
                    $("#"+_frames[i]).css({opacity:0})
                }
                //$("#lastFrame").css({opacity:0})
                animate();

                $("#cover").click(function()
                {
                    gotoActiveLink();
                })


            })

            function gotoActiveLink()
            {
                console.log("active link",_activeLink);
                window.location.href = _links[_activeLink]
            }


        })

        </script>
```

Comment: Go through it and see what it does first.

Comment: Note: You do not need `$(window).load` inside `$(document).ready()` unless you are waiting for images to load completely too (which can take a lot longer than initial page load).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open new windows, rather than using links, so you need to use `window.open()` instead of just changing the *current* browser window URL with `window.location`.

Details here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

It includes options for the target type (like "_blank", which also happens to be the default).

- _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is the default
- _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
- _self - URL replaces the current page
- _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
- name - The name of the window (Note: the name does not specify the title of the new window)

Answer (score 2):

[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) can add, get (value) &  modify elements attributes

```
$('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7YL6/)

Comment: Unfortunately my code doesn't seem to generate any <a>-tag, so I can't get this to work. But Thanks anyway!